# CryptographicException while reading .pfx file

Tags: azure, openssl, x509certificate, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I downloaded a PFX file from Azure Key Vault using the CLI:

`az keyvault secret download -f jul15.pfx -n dlis-api-call-xxxx --vault-name dlisIpsTrial --subscription XXXXXXX`

I'm trying to use the certificate in this code:

```
            var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2("jul15.pfx");
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
            handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
```

But I get an error in the `new X509Certificate2("jul15.pfx");` line: `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Cannot find the requested object.`

Here is the full trace:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Cannot find the requested object.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(String fileName)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName)
   at MultiMedia.Dlis.QueryDlisTool.Program.MakeRequest(Options options, String address, Byte[] imageBytes, NormalizedRectangle_1 crop, HashSet`1 requestedOutputs) in E:\DlisIps\src\MultiMedia.Dlis.QueryDlisTool\Program.cs:line 210
   at MultiMedia.Dlis.QueryDlisTool.Program.Run(Options options, Byte[] imageBlob, NormalizedRectangle_1 crop, Dictionary`2 outputFeatures) in E:\DlisIps\src\MultiMedia.Dlis.QueryDlisTool\Program.cs:line 120
```

Any idea on how to resolve this error? Should I download a `.cert` file and associate it with key to make it a `.pfx` file? Should I download a `.pem` instead and try to make it a `.pfx` file?

Also, when I try to install my `jul15.pfx` I get this error:
[image]

Comment: When you download the cert, it is a base64 string, you will need to convert to byte before saving to file.

Answer (score 0):

Key vault certificates can be downloaded as secret. The certificate is base64 encoded. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-download), you can specify the `--encoding` parameter. This should work for you:

```powershell
az keyvault secret download `
  --file jul15.pfx `
  --encoding base64 `
  --name dlis-api-call-xxxx `
  --vault-name dlisIpsTrial `
  --subscription XXXXXXX
```